# pandoc does not print references when .bib file is in YAML

Tags: pandoc, bibtex

To compile a pdf with a bibtex bibliography, I thought it was sufficient to write the YAML as

```
---
title: super awesome paper
author: albert enstein
bibliography: /path/to/bib/file.bib
---
```

and punch this command into the terminal:

```
pandoc test.md -o test.pdf
```

But it does not work. Instead I have to manually add the bib file to the terminal command:

```
pandoc test.md --bibliography=/path/to/bib/file.bib -o test.pdf
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to use the flag `--filter pandoc-citeproc` if you don't want to use the flag `--bibliography=/path/to/bib/file.bib`. This is because using the `--bibliography=` flag is equivalent to writing `--metadata bibliography=FILE --filter pandoc-citeproc` (https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citation-rendering).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your syntax. So I suspect there are spaces somewhere in the path to the file.

A common error is that the variable does not accept spaces, so I would suggest to try `bibliography: "/path/to/bib/file.bib"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly call the `--citeproc` argument to generate a list of references
from the citations

```
pandoc article.md -o article.pdf --citeproc
```

[Pandoc man page](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citation-rendering) on citation rendering:

> "-C, --citeproc
> Process the citations in the file, replacing them with rendered citations and adding a  bibliography.
> Citation  processing will not take place unless bibliographic data is supplied, either through an ex‐
> ternal file specified using the --bibliography option or the bibliography field in metadata, or via a
> references  section  in metadata containing a list of citations in CSL YAML format with Markdown for‐
> matting.  The style is controlled by a CSL stylesheet specified using the --csl  option  or  the  csl
> field in metadata.  (If no stylesheet is specified, the chicago-author-date style will be used by de‐
> fault.)  The citation processing transformation may be applied before or after filters or Lua filters
> (see  --filter, --lua-filter): these transformations are applied in the order they appear on the com‐
> mand line.  For more information, see the section on Citations.
> "