# pandoc does not produce bibliography when biblio file is in YAML-metadata only

Tags: pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

I assume  that inserting a reference to a BibTex bibliography in a YAML-metadata is sufficient for the references to be produced. This is like [pandoc does not print references when .bib file is in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653335/pandoc-does-not-print-references-when-bib-file-is-in-yaml), which was perhaps misunderstood and which has no accepted answer yet.

I have the example input file:

```
---
title: Ontologies of what?
author: auf 
date: 2010-07-29
keywords: homepage
abstract: | 
    What are the objects ontologists talk about. 
    Inconsistencies become visible if one models real objects (cats) and children playthings.
bibliography: "BibTexExample.bib"
---

An example post. With a reference to [@Frank2010a] and more.

## References
```

I invoke the conversion to latex with :

```
pandoc -f markdown -t pdf  postWithReference.markdown -s --verbose -o postWR.pdf -w latex
```

The pdf is produced, but it contains no references and the text is rendered as `With a reference to [@Frank2010a] and more.` demonstrating that the reference file was not used. The title and author is inserted in the pdf, thus the YAML-metadata is read. If I add the reference file on the command line, the output is correctly produce with the reference list.

What am I doing wrong? I want to avoid specifying the bibliography file (as duplication, DRY) on the command line. Is there a general switch to demand bibliography processing and leaving the selection of the bibliography file to the document YAML-metada?

Comment: Once the bibliography has been specified in the yaml front matter, you still need to explicitly call the `--citeproc` argument to generate a list of references from the citations `pandoc article.md -o article.pdf --citeproc`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandoc does not print references when .bib file is in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653335/pandoc-does-not-print-references-when-bib-file-is-in-yaml)

Comment: I read and referenced this question; it does not cover the use case I have.

Comment: Adding the `--citeproc`argument to the pandoc invocation does generate a list of references from the article's citation. This works also when the bibliography is specified in the YAML front matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theo bibliography is inserted by the pandoc-citeproc filter. It will be run automatically when biblioraphy is set via the command lines, but has to be run manually in cases such as yours. Addind `--filter=pandoc-citeproc` will make it work as expected.

Comment: Perfect. It would be valuable, if the documentation would make this clear. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Is it possible to run the citeproc process separately after pandoc was running? My use case is the conversion to HTML. I would need something like: `run pandoc ...; run citeproc .... `, i.e. a sequence of runs.

Comment: No, because pandoc-citeproc needs to be run on pandoc's internal data structure. Can you describe your use case in more detail (idealy in a new question)?Maybe citeproc.js is an option for you.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I can run the pandoc as described but adding citeproc as a filter would have been even easier. I checked the citeproc.js webpage and do not see how citeproc.js would simplify my application beyond what you have suggested with running pandoc with the --filter=pandoc-citeproc switch.

Answer (score 5):

In the more recent version requires `--citeproc` instead of `--filter=pandoc-citeproc`